# Decomposition of the Rational Group Algebra into Endomorphisms of irreducible representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am a third year math undergraduate student. I am currently taking a graduate course in Abstract Analysis and Representation theory and I came across this nice proposition in chapter 3 of Fulton William, Harris Joe : Representation Theory a first course `[1]`. The proposition (3.29) states that the direct sum of the endomorphisms of the irreducible representations of the group is isomorphic to the complex group algebra CG (it basically gives you the decomposition of the group algebra CG). I was wondering if there is a generalization that allows me to do this for other group algebras where the field is no longer Complex numbers or not even semisimple algebra. Is there a generalization that exists to Rational Numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work for any ["splitting field"](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_field) (i.e. as long as the complex irreps are realizable via matrices over a smaller field). It is sufficent that your field $\mathbb{K}$ contains all $e$th roots of unity, where $e$ is the "exponent" of $G$, i.e. the LCM of orders of all $g\in G$. (Note $e$ may be smaller than $n=|G|$.) For smaller fields, as long as $\mathbb{K}[G]$ is still semisimple (i.e. as long as the characteristic of the field does not divide the order of $G$, so Maschke's theorem applies), the algebra $A=\mathbb{K}[G]$ may be written as a direct sum $\bigoplus n_iV_i$ of irreps $V_i$ with multiplicities $n_i$ (i.e. $nV:=\underbrace{V\oplus\cdots\oplus V}_n$ here).

Then the algebra $A$ according to the Artin-Wedderburn theorem is $A\cong \bigoplus \mathrm{End}(n_iV_i)$. Note it is relevant for this that $\hom(V_i,V_j)=0$ for distinct irreps ($i\ne j$). Then, in turn, $\mathrm{End}(nV)$ may be written as $n\times n$ matrices with entries that are themselves from the algebra $D=\mathrm{End}(V)$. When $\mathbb{K}$ is a splitting field, Schur's lemma says every element of $D$ is an isomorphism (of $V$) hence $D=\mathbb{K}$. However, otherwise, $D$ is simply a division algebra over $\mathbb{K}$ (which could be a field extension of $\mathbb{K}$, or a quaternion algebra, or whatever). Thus

$$ A\cong \bigoplus_i M_{n_i}(D_i) $$

where $D_i=\mathrm{End}(V_i)$. (I am sweeping some stuff about "opposite algebras" under the rug.)

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to say a bit more about the "Artin-Wedderburn theorem" that anon mentions:

If $\mathsf k$ is a field and $G$ a finite group acting linearly on $\mathsf k$-vector spaces $V$ and $W$ (on the left), we will write
$$
\begin{split}
\text{Hom}_G(V,W) &= \{\alpha \in \text{Hom}_{\mathsf k}(V,W): \alpha(g(v))= g(\alpha(v)), \forall v \in V, g \in G\},\\
\textit{and } \text{End}_G(V) &= \text{Hom}_G(V,V).
\end{split}
$$

The vector space $\mathsf kG$ of $\mathsf k$-linear combinations of the group elements of $G$ forms an algebra over $\mathsf k$ in a natural way, and thus, via left multiplication, becomes a $G$-representation. Then $\text{End}_G(\mathsf kG)$ is the algebra of linear endomorphisms of $\mathsf kG$ which commute with the action of $G$ by left-multiplication. One obvious candidate for such endomorphisms comes from the fact that left and right multplication commute: if $a,b \in \mathsf kG$ then
$$
g(ab)= (ga).b, \quad \forall a, b \in \mathsf kG, g \in G,
$$
hence if we define $\varphi_b(a) = ab$ to be the operation of multiplying by $b$ on the right, thus for all $x \in \mathsf kG$ we have $g\varphi_b(x) = \varphi_b(g(x))$ and so $\varphi_b \in \text{End}_{G}(\mathsf kG)$.

A bit more thought shows that the map $b\mapsto \varphi_b$ is an anti-homomorphism, that is, for any $a \in \mathsf kG$, we have $\varphi_{b_1}\circ\varphi_{b_2}(a) = (ab_2)b_1 = a(b_2b_1) = \varphi_{b_2b_1}(a)$, that is $\varphi_{b_1b_2} = \varphi_{b_2}\circ\varphi_{b_1}$.

The map $\Phi\colon \mathsf kG \to \text{End}_{\mathsf G}(\mathsf k[G])$ given by $\Phi(b)(x) = \varphi_b(x) = x.b$ is easily seen to have inverse $\Psi\colon \text{End}_G(\mathsf kG) \to \mathsf kG$ where $\Psi(\theta) = \theta(1_G)$, and hence both are anti-isomorphisms. (In fact everything so far works for any finite-dimensional algebra over $\mathsf k$.)

Now if you know that $\mathsf k$-representations of $G$ are semisimple, that is, a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations, and $\text{Hom}_G(U_1,U_2)=0$ unless $U_1$ and $U_2$ are isomorphic (when it is a skew-field),then if $\mathsf kG \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i^{\oplus n_i}$, where the $U_i$ are the distinct isomorphism classes appearing in $\mathsf kG$, it follows that
$$
\begin{split}
\text{End}_{G}(\mathsf kG) &= \bigoplus_{i,j \in I} \text{Hom}_G(U_i^{\oplus n_i}, U_j^{n_j}) = \bigoplus_{i \in I} \text{Hom}_G(U_i\otimes \mathsf k^{n_i}, U_i\otimes \mathsf k^{\otimes n_j})\\
&= \bigoplus_{i,j \in I} \text{End}_G(U_i\otimes \mathsf k^{n_i})  = \bigoplus_{i \in I}\text{Mat}_{n_i}(\mathsf k)\otimes \text{End}_G(U_i).
\end{split}
$$

If $\mathsf k$ is algebraically closed, then $\text{End}_G(U_i)=\mathsf k$, but over non-algebraically closed fields $\text{End}_G(U_i)$ is a skew-field over $\mathsf k$, which can certainly be larger than $\mathsf k$.

A good example to consider is $Q_8 = \{\pm 1, \pm i,\pm j, \pm k\}$ a subgroup of the multiplicative group $\mathbb H$ the quaternions. Over $\mathbb R$ we have $\mathbb R Q_8 \cong \mathbb R^{\oplus 4}\oplus \mathbb H$, while over $\mathbb C$ we find $\mathbb CQ_8 \cong \mathbb C^4 \oplus \text{Mat}_2(\mathbb C)$.